# Keep parent selected while mouseovering the dropdown in boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I'm trying to do is to keep the `<a>` selected while I'm mouseovering the dropdown:
[image]

I tried the `closest` selector but didn't work:

`$('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast").closest("a").css("background-color", "#eee");`

This is my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/gpLa33ad/6/)**. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using CSS:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gpLa33ad/7/).

Obviously adjust selector-complexity as necessary.

Comment: Lol, I was over complicating things! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `css`

the default styles are added for `a` tag  add this styles for `li`

```
.nav > li:hover, .nav > li:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/gpLa33ad/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function so that it toggles bootstrap's `open` class on the `li` element in the dropdown menu after your animation.

```
// Dropdown Menu Fade    
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mega-inner-dropdown").hover(

    function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).children("li").addClass("open");
    },

    function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).children("li").removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/08gxjset/